# Bootstrap/Wordpress menu bugs

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm having weird problems with my mobile drop down menu. When you click the toggle button the menu appears briefly scrolling just below the button then moves to its proper location.

It also doesn't always run, sometimes clicking it has no effect.

You can see it in action by looking at the mobile version of this page (its the menu activated by the hamburger icon in the top right hand corner):

http://u1f8aki.nixweb23.dandomain.dk

And here is the code that creates the menu:

```
                    <div class="mobilenav">
                            <div class="navbar-header">

                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="primary-menu"><?php esc_html_e( '', 'mentordanmark' ); ?>
                                  <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                                  <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                                  <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
                                </button>

                                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                    <?php
                                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                                            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                                            'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu-nav', 
                                            'container_class' => 'mobileDropdownmenu',
                                            'menu_id'             => ' ',
                                        ) );
                                    ?>
                                </div>

                                <div id="blivMentorMenu" class="BlivMentor-Login-Menu" style="display: none">
                                    <?php wp_nav_menu(
                                        'menu=secondary-menu&after=<li class="menu-divider">|</li>'
                                        ); ?>   
                                </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
/* To get the menu to appear */
button.navbar-toggle.collapsed {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
button.navbar-toggle {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
.mobilenav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 5.7em;
    width: 100%;
}

    #primary-menu-nav {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 5.7em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4ea;
        padding-top: 4em;
    }

    #primary-menu-nav a {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1em;
        min-width: 15em;
        text-align: center;
    }

    button.menu-toggle {
        border: 0;
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1.4em;
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }

    button.menu-toggle:active, button.menu-toggle:focus, a.btn-navbar:active, a.btn-navbar:focus {
        border: 0 !important;
        outline: 0;
    }

    a.btn-navbar {
        display: flex;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2.5em;
        height: 3em;
        width: 3em;
        padding: .3em 0;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    span.icon-bar {
        background: #000;
        height: .3em;
        width: 100%;
        margin: .2em;
    }
```

Comment: You need to post relevant code inside your question instead of linking to third-party websites (even if the website is your own).

Comment: I've added code snippets if you could reopen the question. I'm not entire sure they're even whats responsible for the behaviour hence why i posted the link. I suspect its somewhere deeper within bootstraps base code possibly, but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Bootstrap 4 code if you want to use Bootstrap 4 css.

Bootstrap 3 code is incompatible with Bootstrap 4 css.

Here's what a basic Bootstrap 4 navbar looks like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please remember: "avoid trying to answer questions which...
...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem ...require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions"